# Real time notification with Node.JS, Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I know this is not a good question for this forum, but I really need your help.

I am developing an application with `MEAN`(MongoDB, Express.JS, Angular.JS and Node.js).

I need to implement a notification feature similar to `Facebook` for user activities like I created a `blog` and some one can `comment` on it or `update` the `blog`, I want to know  all the activities with the help of `notification`

I am looking at `socket.io` for real time activities.

Can I get any alternate to implement for that feature?

I want your suggestion that what will be better for me to implement this feature.

Any suggestion will be helpful for me to get that things.

*Thank You*

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883540/http-server-to-client-push-technologies-standards-libraries

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), which combined to your technologies may be the right thing to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing with a chat system that was previously using PHP and AJAX (which is not the most efficient way to do things that are constantly needing to poll for updates).

I used a range of frameworks to rebuild my app such as socket.io, it was a bit tedious to learn for me. However, it works really well. I guess a notification feature, in principle would work similar to a instant messenger client - so there maybe some good tutorials on the web that you can adapt for that.

I highly recommend socket.io

Comment: Can you provide any link where I can adopt that things, I spent time but didn't get any useful place

Comment: You can see small tutorials like that of http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ - you can adapt that to then just messages to authenticated users logged in to your mongodb - I think that's kind of the same principle. Good luck